# Why Angular ReactiveForms FormArray throws error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'updateOn' of null"

Tags: angular6, angular-reactive-forms, form-control, formarray

Hello All I have a Formarray which which has set of Roles. During Edit it dynamically removes & adds roles in that form array till here all works fine, but when i submit the form it thorws error & the page gets refresh.

Error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'updateOn' of null

Also I am attaching the screen shot below[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

it is worked for Me

Make sure you have put `<button type="button" ></button>` instead of `<input type="submit" />`

```
<button [ngClass]="(this.editMemberForm.invalid?'a1':'')" type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="saveData()">Save</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

##### Have a close look at what you're doing on your formGroup

For me doing some
**formGroup.removeControl("somefield");**

raised the same error.